# I am Canadian and own a cottage in the US. I want to gift it to my 2 Canadian children. What are the tax implications

Tags: united-states, canada, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, gift-tax

I own a cottage in Point Roberts Wash. I am a resident of Canada and want to gift it to my son who is also Canadian, What taxes apply to this transaction?

Comment: I'm sure a tax attorney in Washington will be able to answer this quickly.